# 2D Map representation of GPS coordinates in degrees

Tags: navigation, gps

I want to implement my own GPS navigation for a quad-copter.
I can calculate and filter the GPS coordinates (latitude and longitude in degrees).

I believe the easiest approach for me would be, to calculate the change of the heading of the quad-copter from the current attitude to the destination point and let it fly straight on after turning.

However I am not sure about the 2D representation of the latitude/longitude-GPS coordinates (for a round earth to a 2D map system when calculating the heading change). How big is the expected error? Or is there none?

Comment: Have a look at [world geodetic systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) (especially WGS84). Also, on a somewhat related note, you can use [USGS's earth explorer portal](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) to download anything from satellite imagery to digital elevation models (free registration required though).

Answer (score 1):

If the expected range of your quadcopter's journeys is under 10 miles, the error between spherical and flat geometry is less than the GPS's poistion error...assuming you are using normal GPS, not dGPS. As a rough rule of thumb, 2D mapping works to the horizon!

Comment: Very interesting way of thinking about GPS errors and errors induced when converting between spherical/flat. Could you however perhaps elaborate a bit more on what you mean by 2D mapping works to the horizon.

Comment: I was just asking this question myself yesterday and was thinking how to calculate the error.

Comment: Sorry, the horizon remark was in the nature of a joke: the horizon is 'visible' because its where the curvature of the earth has become 'visible'

Comment: I believe this page covers the problems and answers in much greater detail than I ever could: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/visual/home/proj/tiger/gisfaq.html In particular, note Bob Chamberlain's message on range errors part way down the page.